# Python Regexs Unit Testing

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing

I am trying to do some unit testing on a little regex def.

```
x = "TEST TEST TEST. Regular Expressions. TEST TEST TEST"

def find_start_end(phrase,sample_set):
    m = re.search(phrase, sample_set)

    start = m.start()
    end = m.end()
    return (start,end)
    #print(start,end)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    print(find_start_end("Regular Expressions", x))
```

This returns (16,35)....

My testing Unit is....

```
import unittest

class TestAlpha(unittest.TestCase):


def test_1(self):
    x = "Regular Expressions"
    self.assertEqual((0, 19), find_start_end("Regular Expressions", x))

def test_2(self):
        x = "TEST TEST TEST. Regular Expression. TEST TEST TEST"
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError, find_start_end("Regular Expressions", x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Test 1 passes fine, my question is on test_2 how do I test for the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'`.

I was trying to use `assertRaises`, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am open to any suggestions that would work better. Just trying to figure out how to test for the `NoneType`. I am very new to regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is using [`TestCase.assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) wrong way.

Replace following line:

```
self.assertRaises(AttributeError, find_start_end("Regular Expressions", x))
```

with:

```
# Do not call `find_start_end` directly,
#   but pass the function and its arguments to assertRaises
self.assertRaises(AttributeError, find_start_end, "Regular Expressions", x)
```

or:

```
# Use assertRaises as context manager
with self.assertRaises(AttributeError)
    find_start_end("Regular Expressions", x)
```

Comment: ok that works Thanks. So in def assertRaises(self, excClass, callableObj=None, *args, **kwargs):    "Regular Expressions" and x are my ** args?

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying, Yes, they are. I added commented to the answer code.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying, BTW, `(m.start(), m.end())` could be expressed as `m.span()`.